# Having issue importing tablerates.csv on Magento 2 with custom Region/State

Tags: shipping, import, shipping-methods, table-rates

I have added New Region/States for the Country Malaysia in the table directory_country_region and also directory_country_region_name..
see screenshot:
[image]

as you can see from the screenshot.. country code is MY and the region/state code is MY-01 and etc..

now look at my tablerates.csv.. see screenshot below:
[image]
i have matched the region/state id to be the same as the one in the mysql database table.. where MY-01 and etc..

but i still get this error after importing (refer to screenshot):
[image]

what am i doing wrong? any magento expert please provide your insight.. thanks!~ and appreciate any help i can get..

Comment: Verify Country Id, in database it show "MY" and in your CSV it show "MYS".

Comment: hi sorry.. that was the wrong screenshot.. i have tested it with MY as well and i get the same result.. same error even with MY

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. For anybody having issues importing the tablerates.csv file even after adding the region/state rows in *directory_country_region* and *directory_country_regions_name* tables. Be sure to confirm that you are using the same **region code** (not region name) in both the tablerates.csv  file and in the *directory_country_region* . Magento uses the region code and not the region name when importing the tables.csv file.